# how to convert pdfkit object into buffer using nodejs

Tags: node.js, response, pdfkit

I am generating pdf document using pdfkit(nodejs module).i need to convert the pdfkit object to buffer and send response as attachment file without save a file in server.

i was using output function to achieve this:

```
pdfdocument.output(function(buffer){
    return buffer;
});
```

pdfkit deprecated the output function.

so right now i dont know how to do
any idea...

Comment: how can i make my pdf document not to be saved in server ?

Answer (score 36):

Working example for pdfkit v0.8.0:

```
let pdf = new pdfkit();

let buffers = [];
pdf.on('data', buffers.push.bind(buffers));
pdf.on('end', () => {

    let pdfData = Buffer.concat(buffers);

    // ... now send pdfData as attachment ...

});

pdf.text('Hello', 100, 100);
pdf.end();
```

Hope it helps :)