# PDFKit send PDF back to client from Express Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdfkit

I have an express server that has a PDF generation endpoint using PDFKit.

```
this.app.post("/print", (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
            const header = { ...req.body };
            printHandlers.execute(header).then(pdf => {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename='+header.po_num+'.pdf'
                });
                console.log(pdf);
                return res.end(pdf);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
```

This is code that actually generates the PDF:

```
//creates new pdf object

.then((location) => {
                        let pdfObj = new createPDF(obj, buffer, location);
                        //console.log(pdfObj)
                        pdfObj.generate();
                        return pdfObj;
                    })
```

This is the generate() method:

```
generate(){
        let output = new PDFGenerator();

        const fileName: string = `${this.data.header.po_num}.pdf`;
        const stream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)

        output.pipe(stream);

        this.generateHeaders(output);
        output.moveDown();
        this.generateTable(output);
        output.end();
    }
```

I am trying to send the PDF back to the client, and I am struggling on how to do this? Using arrayBuffer? Any other ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686843/how-to-convert-pdfkit-object-into-buffer-using-nodejs

Comment: convert pdf generated to buffer and simply put res.send(buffer)